# Внутренний контур полигона вырезается, только если добавлять его как одиночный объект

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Если полигон с внутренним контуром добавляю на карту так:

```
      var myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
        geometry: {
          type: "Polygon",
          coordinates: [
                        [
                         [53.34, 43.07], [65.92, 81.91], [50.40, 98.90]
                        ], 
                        [
                         [53.50, 82.48], [58.42, 87.57], [58.05, 75.04]
                        ]
                       ]
        }
      });
      myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);
```

То он отображается правильно (с внутренним вырезанным контуром).

Если же добавляю его через ObjectManager, то внутренний контур не вырезается:

```
objectManagerSourses.add({
    type: 'Feature',
    id: 7777,
    geometry: {
        type: 'Polygon',
        coordinates: [
                      [
                       [53.34, 43.07], [65.92, 81.91], [50.40, 98.90]
                      ], 
                      [
                       [53.34, 43.07], [65.92, 81.91], [50.40, 98.90]
                      ]
                     ]
    }
});
myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManagerSourses);
```

Как можно добавить на карту большое количество подобных полигонов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прописывайте полигонам **[fillRule](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/geometry.json.polygon.html#field_detail__fillRule)** как **evenOdd**. Для обычных полигонов API Яндекс Карт это значение и так задаётся по умолчанию, но в **ObjectManager** оно по дефолту почему-то **nonZero**.

```
objectManagerSourses.add({
    type: 'Feature',
    id: 7777,
    geometry: {
        type: 'Polygon',
        coordinates: [
            [[53.34, 43.07], [65.92, 81.91], [50.40, 98.90]], 
            [[53.34, 43.07], [65.92, 81.91], [50.40, 98.90]]
            ],
        fillRule: "evenOdd"
    }
});
```

По работе же с большим числом объектов у Яндекса в документации описано [несколько возможных вариантов](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/many-objects.html) - выбирайте, какой вам реализовать будет удобней.